# Translation of text in pdf aligned page-by-page

Tags: two-column, pdfpages, alignment, translate

I have a book in one language in pdf format and want to write its translation next to it, on a page-by-page basis. Are there any packages that will simplify this?

I've set up my document in landscape A4 and want to put the pages from the pdf on the left and the translation to the right.

I first looked at `pdfpages`. This makes it possible to include the pdf in one go, which is convenient. But it is not clear to me how to left-align the included pages and write to their right.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
  \includepdf[pages=-,frame]{original.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Then I looked at `pdfoverlay`. This almost does what I want, but again I do not know how to put the pdf page on the left and the translation on the right.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfoverlay}
\pdfoverlaySetPDF{original.pdf}

\begin{document}
***title page***

\pagebreak % 2-3

***metadata and abstract***

\pagebreak % 3-4

***
\end{document}
```

Next I investigated the `parallel`, `parcolumns`, and `paracol` packages, but these are not aimed at including the original as pdf pages.

Ideally, I would like to be able to only show the non-dummy original pages I select, because including all pdf pages is time-consuming when compiling.
There should be no important restrictions on the LaTeX we can include in the translation side: figures, tables, footnotes, etc. should all be possible.
Of course the translator is responsible for making the translation fit the space available. (We can play with font and page size to make that easy.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this could work (the actual layout needs perhaps adjustments, and if your translation takes more than a page, the code to retrieve the next original page should be more sophisticated):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,left=16cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\AtPageLowerLeft{\includegraphics[page=\value{page},width=15cm]{example-image-a4-numbered}}}
\begin{document}
  
  some text translating page 1
  \newpage
  some text translating page 2
  \newpage
  some text translating page 3
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think `pdfpages` can be replaced by `graphicx` here.

Comment: Showing all pdf pages without having to add many `\newpage`s and leaving non-translated pages empty is quite important. So while interesting, this answer does not solve my problem.

Comment: you will have to add \newpage command somehow if you want to do page by page translation. How should LaTeX know that a text refers to the next page if you don't tell it?

Comment: Yes, `\newpages` will be necessary. But that is not the issue I'm trying to explain. I see it as follows: there are three lists (i) pdf pages, (ii) page numbers on which to show pdf page and not a dummy (to be supplied in preamble), and (iii) translation (material between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`; separator is `\newpage`). For each pdf page, LaTeX should check whether it or a dummy should be shown, but always create a page with output. If there is a corresponding item in the translation material list (even if it is empty), it should be put next to the pdf or dummy page.

Comment: and where is the problem? I use page 1 of the included pdf on page 1, and 2 on 2, but this can be easily changed. Replace  `page=\value{page}` by whatever relation you think more sensible.